# Windows event in Json Format using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I would like to windows archived events and convert them into Json format.
I am doing the below.

```
New-PSDrive -Name P -Root "\\$netappip\etc$\log" -PSProvider FileSystem -Credential $cred
$WinEvtJson=Get-WinEvent -Path "P:\adtlog.20131021141037.evt" -Oldest | Format-List -Property * | ConvertTo-Json
$WinEvtJson
Remove-PSDrive P
```

I get the result as

> [
>       {
>           "pageHeaderEntry":  null,
>           "pageFooterEntry":  null,
>           "autosizeInfo":  null,
>           "shapeInfo":  {
>                             "ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd":  "830bdcb24c1642258724e441512233a4"
>                         },
>           "groupingEntry":  null,
>           "ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd":  "033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280"
>       },
>       {
>           "shapeInfo":  null,
>           "groupingEntry":  null,
>           "ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd":  "9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3"
>       },
>       {
>           "formatEntryInfo":  {
>                                   "listViewFieldList":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.For mat.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShel l.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewFi eld
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Int ernal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField Microsoft.
>   PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.L istViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Com mands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField M
>   icrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal .Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.Power Shell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewField",
>                                   "ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd": 
>   "cf58f450baa848ef8eb3504008be6978"
>                               },
>           "outOfBand":  false,
>           "writeStream":  0,
>           "ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd":  "27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c"
>       },
>       {
>           "groupingEntry":  null,
>           "ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd":  "4ec4f0187cb04f4cb6973460dfe252df"
>       },
>       {
>           "groupingEntry":  null,
>           "ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd":  "cf522b78d86c486691226b40aa69e95c"
>       } ]

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you use the `Format-*` cmdlets, treat that as the end of the line for that pipeline or collection of data. `Format-*` changes your data into strings suitable for display, and nothing more - rendering it useless for any other processing or use by any other cmdlet. Try this:

```
New-PSDrive -Name P -Root "\\$netappip\etc$\log" -PSProvider FileSystem -Credential $cred
$WinEvtJson=Get-WinEvent -Path "P:\adtlog.20131021141037.evt" -Oldest | ConvertTo-Json
$WinEvtJson
Remove-PSDrive P
```